# Why is it that when potential difference across a capacitor is equal to the supply voltage, no flow occurs?

Tags: electricity, charge, capacitance

Can someone explain to me how and why this happens? I'm really confused. I'm also confused about how the net charge between 2 plates is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The flow of charge is driven by a potential difference. If the potential difference is zero, so is the flow. This is shown in Ohms law: V=IR. If V=0, I=0.

In a capacitor, "charging" it removes charge from one side and moves it to the other. The total or net amount of charge inside does not vary. It is just rearranged. Moving all the furniture in your home from floor to ceiling would not increase or decrease the amount of furniture, it would only increase the amount of gravitational potential energy stored in your home (temporarily).

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is defined as the work done to bring a unit charge from infinity to a point.

This means if an electrode have a very high Positive Voltage, you will need a very big force to move another Positive Charge into that electrode.

If a capacitor stores charge, its voltage will increase ( since like charges repel ). And it will be harder for new charges to go in. Until one point the capacitor will have a Voltage similar to the Supply. In that case, no more current can flow because they both have the same strength, non of them can push charge into the other position.

The net charge between the plate is 0 because a supply ( battery ) cannot produce more Positive Charge than the Negative Charge. Or more Negative Charge than the Positive Charge. So the Cathode and Anode will be charged equally at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

Once the capacitor has been charged to the potential of the source, there is no longer a potential difference between the source's termianals and the respective plates or terminals of the capacitor itself. The flow only exists when there is a potential difference between the source and the capacitor. With AC, there is always a potential difference due to the change in polarity of the source, hence it appears that there is a constant flow even when the source and the capacitor are at the same potential